# Questions about thread-safety of nftw() and ftw()

Tags: c, thread-safety, manpage

I read two man pages([ftw](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftw.html), [nftw](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html)) from opengroup.org, so I thought `ftw()` and `nftw()` do not guarantee thread-safety.

But I've found another [page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) about these functions from man7.org, which says `ftw()` is MT-safe and `nftw()` is `MT-safe cwd`.

And these functions are in thread-safety exception list, in this [page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

For now, I still believe these functions don't guarantee thread-safety. But I wonder why does [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) say `ftw()` is MT-safe.

Why does the page from man7.org say `ftw()` is MT-safe?

Is it based on POSIX standard?

Comment: The POSIX reference says that the functions doesn't need to be thread-safe, it's up to the specific implementations. Also note that the POSIX reference also says that `ftw` is marked as obsolescent, so please try to avoid using it.

Comment: The *Attributes* section in all man pages in the [Linux man pages project](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/) refer to the GNU C library implementation, as explained in the [man 7 attributes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/attributes.7.html) page explaining that section. So, those attributes apply if you are using the GNU C library.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answer. But I still wonder why does the page from man7.org say `ftw()` is MT-sfae? Is it based on POSIX?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that POSIX says a function is not multithread-safe only means "it is not guaranteed to be multithread-safe", so you cannot expect it to be or rely that it is. However, it does not mean that it is forbidden for implementations to make it multithread-safe. Implementations may always apply stronger guarantees than the standard requires, they just must not apply weaker ones.